# Copying files from Jenkin workspace (from inside docker container) to local drive

Tags: java, docker

I have Jenkin running in my docker container, I have a jar file in my Jenkin workspace.

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myproject/target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am trying to do like :

```
jenkins@1911a08cab06:~/workspace/myproject/target$ cp myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /Users/xyz/Desktop/folder1

cp: cannot create regular file '/Users/xyz/Desktop/folder1': No such file or directory
```

I know  with **docker cp** command,  we can copy it but i want same from inside the container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most ideal method is to use `docker cp` command.

However, if it does not meet your need, the only way you can do it within your docker container is:

1. Recreate your container and mount the path in your local machine to the container like

```
-v /Users/xyz/Desktop/folder1:/directory_to_copy
```

2. Recreate your snapshot.
3. In your container, you can copy the file like this

```
jenkins@1911a08cab06:~/workspace/myproject/target$ cp myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /directory_to_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker cp <contaier_name>:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myproject/target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /Users/xyz/Desktop/folder1
```

You need to run the command from outside the container (on the host).

`docker cp --help` for more details